# Docker pull fails when using the HTTP exposed API

Tags: docker, authentication, dockerhub, docker-pull

What I am trying to do

I need to be able pull private image that is stored in Docker hub when using the exposed daemon over http

```
http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.35/images/create?fromImage=akkovachev/test-repository
```

The "akkovachev/test-repository" is a private repo in docker hub, when I run the above POST request I get

```
{
    "message": "pull access denied for akkovachev/test-repository, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"
}
```

So probably there's something I am missing but I don't understand what. What I tried to do is change the auth with base64 encoded uname:password in the  file

> ./docker/config.json

I have also tried the base64 encoded header in the format described here https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.35/#section/Authentication but again the same issue. I am posting here as my last resort, as I was unable to find a good explanation of why this happens. Many people are saying they are facing the same problem but mostly in the CLI. I am using Docker version v20.10.5 for windows.

It's important to note that the issue occurs only when I try to do that via the HTTP exposed demon. It works fine when I do In the CLI

```
docker pull akkovachev/test-repository
```

Evertyghing works as expected the image is beeing pulled correctly

I need to be able to pull through the API as I've my own Rest api build around that and i need to be able to pull through the exposed docker daemon.

Headers i am using in Postman
[image]

Comment: Turning on that HTTP API is really really dangerous; why are you trying to interact with Docker this way?  Can you use a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) instead of trying to make the HTTP calls yourself?

Comment: can you also share the body and headers of the request?

Comment: I am not exposing the http API, over the internet that works only locally. I am using https://github.com/amihaiemil/docker-java-api which is listed in the Docker SDK page (Unofficial). The problem is that it fails even there. And I believe that behind the scenes is using the Daemon exposed over tcp.  In fact the above http call is pulled from the Stack trace that is thrown when I try to Create Image from private repo.

Answer (score 0):

I have mange to figure it out. The problem was in the base64 encoded string that we pass as a X-Registry-Auth header. I was missing the "serveraddress" property in json

```
{
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "serveraddress": "string"
}
```

i added that and pointed to the https://index.docker.io/v1/ then it worked just fine